# Calculating progress

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a basic progress bar with jQuery. I got al the parts that will display the progress in percentages, just need to debug my math.

So, if I start with 130 questions, every time the question is answered I need to recalculate and show the progress.

So here's what I do

```
var questID // is current question ID, from 1 to 130

var startCount = 130;
var currentCount = startCount - questID;
var progress = Math.floor(currentCount / startCount * 100);
$("#progressBar").width(progress);
```

I think I get something backwards as when I test I get 99% after the first question... probably need more caffeine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `currentCount` logic is wrong. If you have answered 1 question then:

```
var currentCount = 130 - 1 = 129.
```

Then `129/130` will give you the 99%. You just need `1/130`. Therefore you can use `questID`:

```
var questID // is current question ID, from 1 to 130

var startCount = 130;
var progress = Math.floor(questID / startCount * 100);
$("#progressBar").width(progress);
```

Comment: Looks like we are on the same wavelength. We both posted the same answer and made almost the same edit. At the same time.

Comment: @Enrico Great minds think alike! That, or we're both high on caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, you got it backward. questID *is* the currentCount you were trying to calculate. No need to subtract it from startCount.

```
var questID // is current question ID, from 1 to 130

var startCount = 130;
var progress = Math.floor(questID/ startCount * 100);
$("#progressBar").width(progress);
```

Time for a coffee.